# Social Sharing Button On Affiliate Marketing Page in Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, social-buttons, affiliate

I want to add **social sharing button** in **affiliate marketing material** page.which is use for customer to sharing link through social sites.
so there is any extention??if not then how to create custom button integration?
if anyone know then help me...

Comment: you will get free extension for same

Comment: i get addthis extention which is only product page.

Comment: you can customized it as per requirement where you want in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use AddThis website tools. Find it searching on google

open your theme page.xml layout file and in before_body_end section add

```
<![CDATA[
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=[YOUR PUB ID]" async="async"></script>
]]>
```

To add the code to a specific page open your page .phtml file and copy the code of your tool where you like.

You need to get your code and Pub Id from addthis admin panel of course